# How can I test that the bash interactive shell handles the signal using the handler that I set up via `trap`?

Tags: bash, signals, trap

In a bash interactive shell, when I run a `trap` command (e.g. `trap "echo You hit control-C!" INT`) to set up a signal handler, does that set up how the bash interactive shell handles the signal?

How can I test that the bash interactive shell handles the signal by using the handler that I set up via `trap`?

Is it possible to test i.e. to generate the signal

- within the bash interactive shell?
- within the terminal emulator where the shell runs?

Or must I test from the outside of the bash interactive shell, or outside the terminal emulator?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen, and what's happening instead? The *definition* of trap is "The commands in arg are to be read and executed when the shell receives signal sigspec."

Comment: I would like to know how to show that an interactive shell reacts to a signal for which a trap has been set in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test a handler from inside the shell it’s set up in, by using `kill` to send a signal to the current shell:

```
kill -INT $$
```

Change `-INT` to match the trap you wish to test.